# Can we find out if there is an increase to number of requests to a given page?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

If i have a web app in Azure, with ApplicationInsights configured, is there a way we can tell if there was an increase in the number of requests to a given page?

I know we can get the "Delta" of **performance** in a given time slice, compared to the previous period, but doesn't seem like we can do this for **requests**?

For example, i'd like to answer questions like: "what pages in the last hour had the highest % increase in requests, compared to the previous period"?

Does anyone know how to do this, or can it be done via the AppInsights query language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether it can be done using the Portal, I don't think so. But I came up with the following Kusto query:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(2h) and timestamp < ago(1h)
| summarize previousPeriod = todouble(count()) by url
| join (
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize lastHour = todouble(count()) by url
) on url
| project url, previousPeriod, lastHour, change = ((lastHour - previousPeriod) / previousPeriod) * 100
| order by change desc
```

This is about increase/decrease of amount of traffic per url, you can change `count()` to for example `avg(duration)` to get the increase/decrease of the average duration.